# Google Search Console API: How do you implement multiple OR filters?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-webmasters

After much fiddling, I've finally got the Search Console API working. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to add multiple OR filters. I presume this is what dimensionFilterGroups[].groupType will eventually be for, but 'or' is not yet an option.

Basically, how do you implement a series of filters where the results are returned when any are true?

I've tried the following, but none seem to work:

```
"dimensionFilterGroups": [
  {
    "filters": [
      {
        "dimension": 'query',
        "operator": 'equals',
        "expression": 'lockers'
      },
      {
        "dimension": 'query',
        "operator": 'equals',
        "expression": 'shelving'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
"dimensionFilterGroups": [
  {
    "filters": [
      {
        "dimension": 'query',
        "operator": 'equals',
        "expression": 'lockers'
      }
    ],
    "filters": [
      {
        "dimension": 'query',
        "operator": 'equals',
        "expression": 'shelving'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
"filters": [
  {
    "dimension": 'query',
    "operator": 'equals',
    "expression": 'lockers'
  },
  {
    "dimension": 'query',
    "operator": 'equals',
    "expression": 'shelving'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this still isn't supported according to the documentation.

dimensionFilterGroups[].groupType:

> "Whether all filters in this group must return true ("and"), or one or
>   more must return true (not yet supported)."

Source: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query

Comment: Thanks Martin - I believe I read that somewhere but was hoping it was outdated! In the end I was forced to simply send multiple requests. It's a little odd that this isn't supported, as it seems to put unnecessary load on Google's servers.

Comment: I was hoping now it is. Its like four years after

Comment: Still not implemented. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same. I guess the intuitive way would have been allowing other logical operators ("or", for example), but that's not possible. However, I achieved what I needed using the "includingRegex" filter operator. For example, for getting information only if the countries are either *United States of America* or *Japan*:

```
"dimensionFilterGroups": [
    {
      "groupType": "and",
      "filters": [
        {
          "dimension": "country",
          "operator": "includingRegex",
          "expression": "usa|jpn"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```